# Vue test-utils how to test a router.push()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-test-utils

In my component , I have a method which will execute a `router.push()`

```
import router from "@/router";
// ...
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    closeAlert: function() {
      if (this.msgTypeContactForm == "success") {
        router.push("/home");
      } else {
        return;
      }
    },
    // ....
  }
}
```

I want to test it...

I wrote the following specs..

```
it("should ... go to home page", async () => {
    // given
    const $route = {
      name: "home"
    },
    options = {
      ...
      mocks: {
        $route
      }
    };
    wrapper = mount(ContactForm, options);
    const closeBtn = wrapper.find(".v-alert__dismissible");
    closeBtn.trigger("click");
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(alert.attributes().style).toBe("display: none;")
    // router path '/home' to be called ?
  });
```

1 - I get an error

```
console.error node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:15
[vue-test-utils]: could not overwrite property $route, this is usually caused by a plugin that has added the property asa read-only value
```

2 - How I should write the expect() to be sure that this /home route has been called

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are doing something that happens to work, but I believe is wrong, and also is causing you problems to test the router. You're importing the router in your component:

```
import router from "@/router";
```

Then calling its `push` right away:

```
router.push("/home");
```

I don't know how exactly you're installing the router, but usually you do something like:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
}).$mount('#app');
```

To install Vue plugins. I bet you're already doing this (in fact, is this mechanism that expose `$route` to your component). In the example, a vuex store and a reference to vue-i18n are also being installed.

This will expose a `$router` member in **all your components**. Instead of importing the router and calling its `push` directly, you could call it from `this` as `$router`:

```
this.$router.push("/home");
```

Now, thise makes testing easier, because you can pass a fake router to your component, when testing, via the `mocks` property, just as you're doing with `$route` already:

```
  const push = jest.fn();
  const $router = {
    push: jest.fn(),
  }
  ...
  mocks: {
    $route,
    $router,
  }
```

And then, in your test, you assert against `push` having been called:

```
  expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/the-desired-path');
```

Comment: You are right ... I installed the router as you mentioned... and I understand better why I could not mock the router ... !! thanks a lot  I am going to test it now ..  How $route should be defined ?

Comment: i still get `[vue-test-utils]: could not overwrite property $route, this is usually caused by a plugin that has added the property asa read-only value` error

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have setup the pre-requisities correctly and similar to [this](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vue-router.html#mocking-route-and-router)

Just use

```
it("should ... go to home page", async () => {
    const $route = {
      name: "home"
    }

  ...

  // router path '/home' to be called ?
  expect(wrapper.vm.$route.name).toBe($route.name)
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot ...  it works with :  expect(wrapper.vm.$route.name).toBe($route.name) ... not $rout.path

Comment: Oops, sorry. The `$route.path` was what I have used and a muscle memory. I hope this have helped you